# Is there a way to keep the keyboard open even when input loses focus/prevent blur on React Native?

Tags: react-native

I am trying to achieve the same effect as in the native 'notes' app. Basically, I have a text input which covers 95% of the screen and I have a small button at the bottom. Tapping the button once should trigger the button's `onPress` event. Instead, the tap just blurs the text input and I have to tap again on the button in order to trigger it's `onPress` event.

I would also like to know how to force the keyboard to stay open even when the input is blurred.

Thanks.

Answer (score 12):

Any ScrollView make close you keyboard. 
If you use nested elements, don't forgot to add a property to the parent scrollView **keyboardShouldPersistTaps="always"**. And add  **blurOnSubmit={false}** for keyboard don't blinked when you submit ended.

```
<ScrollView keyboardShouldPersistTaps="handled">    

    <ScrollView keyboardShouldPersistTaps="always">
      <TextInput           
        placeholder="First field"
        returnKeyType="next"
        blurOnSubmit={false}
        onSubmitEditing={() => {
          this.textInput.focus();
        }}
      />

      <TxtInput
        placeholder="Second"
        getRef={(e) => {
          this.textInput = e;
        }}
        returnKeyType="done"
      />
    </ScrollView>

</ScrollView>
```

Work in RN v 0.55.3

Answer (score 3):

A few workarounds for this issue have been posted in Github (where I think you posted this question aswell).

For the sake of helping others that are running into this issue, you can find the full discussion here:

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4229

In my case the problem was caused by the `<ScrollView/>` wrapping my input and submit buttons.

Adding the following properties to the ScrollView made it so I could submit, but scrolling still dismissed the keyboard.

```
    <ScrollView
        keyboardShouldPersistTaps={true}
        keyboardDismissMode='on-drag'
        ref = 'scrollView'
        automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false}
        horizontal={false}
        style={styles.scrollView}>

        {pagecontent}
        ...
    </ScrollView>
```